# Separate title string with no spaces into words

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find and separate words in a title that has no spaces.

Before:

> ThisIsAnExampleTitleHELLO-WORLD2019T.E.S.T.(Test)"Test"'Test'[Test]

After:

> This Is An Example Title HELLO-WORLD 2019 T.E.S.T. (Test) [Test] "Test" 'Test'

---

I'm looking for a regular expression rule that can do the following.

I thought I'd identify each word if it starts with an uppercase letter.

But also preserve all uppercase words as not to space them into `A L L U P P E R C A S E`.

Additional rules:

- Space a letter if it touches a number: `Hello2019World` `Hello 2019 World`
- Ignore spacing initials that contain periods, hyphens, or underscores `T.E.S.T.`
- Ignore spacing if between brackets, parentheses, or quotes `[Test] (Test) "Test" 'Test'`
- Preserve hyphens `Hello-World`

---

**C#**

https://rextester.com/GAZJS38767

```
// Title without spaces
string title = "ThisIsAnExampleTitleHELLO-WORLD2019T.E.S.T.(Test)[Test]\"Test\"'Test'";

// Detect where to space words
string[] split =  Regex.Split(title, "(?<!^)(?=(?<![.\\-'\"([{])[A-Z][\\d+]?)");

// Trim each word of extra spaces before joining
split = (from e in split
         select e.Trim()).ToArray();

// Join into new title
string newtitle = string.Join(" ", split);

// Display
Console.WriteLine(newtitle);
```

---

**Regular expression**

I'm having trouble with spacing before the numbers, brackets, parentheses, and quotes.

https://regex101.com/r/9IIYGX/1

```
(?<!^)(?=(?<![.\-'"([{])(?<![A-Z])[A-Z][\d+?]?)

(?<!^)          // Negative look behind

(?=             // Positive look ahead

(?<![.\-'"([{]) // Ignore if starts with punctuation
(?<![A-Z])      // Ignore if starts with double Uppercase letter
[A-Z]           // Space after each Uppercase letter
[\d+]?          // Space after number

)
```

---

#### Solution

Thanks for all your combined effort in answers. Here's a Regex example. I'm applying this to file names and have exclude special characters `\/:*?"<>|`.

https://rextester.com/FYEVE73725

https://regex101.com/r/xi8L4z/1

Comment: I am *up-voting* because its the first post i have seen in hours that has an appropriate amount of information, research and effort

Comment: @MichaelRandall And sadly, that is a better track record than what I see coming on the site during most weekend days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First few parts are similar to [@revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55096729/3654837): `(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}`, additionally I add the following regex to space between number and letter: `(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])` and to detect `OTPIsADevice` then replace with lookahead and lookbehind to find uppercase with a lowercase: `(((?<!^)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))`

Note that `|` is or operator which allowed all the regex to be executed.

Regex: `(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])|(((?<!^)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FwHTzI/2)

### Update

Improvised a bit:

From: `(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])`

into: `(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}|(?<=\p{L})\d` which do the same thing.

`(((?<!^)(?<!\p{P})[A-Z](?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))|(?<!^)(?=[[({&])|(?<=[)\]}!&}])` improvised from [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095949/separate-title-string-with-no-spaces-into-words/55099745#comment96968406_55099745) which is adding exception to some punctuation: `(((?<!^)(?<!['([{])[A-Z](?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))|(?<!^)(?=[[({&])|(?<=[)\\]}!&}])`

Final regex:
`(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}|(?<=\p{L})\d|(((?<!^)(?<!\p{P})[A-Z](?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))|(?<!^)(?=[[({&])|(?<=[)\]}!&}])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MhPYer/1)

Comment: This is almost working perfect. One issue, somewhere in the last part `|(((?<!^)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))` is not preserving the parentheses, brackets, and quotes. https://rextester.com/BTA83734

Comment: Thanks, your regex has solved the single letter problem. I've added some extra rules at the end to handle the other issues. https://rextester.com/FYEVE73725

Answer (score 19):

Here is a regex which seems to work well, at least for your sample input:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=\W)(?=\W)
```

This patten says to make a split on a boundary of one of the following conditions:

- what precedes is a lowercase, and what precedes is an uppercase (or
  vice-versa)
- what precedes is a digit and what follows is a letter (or
  vice-versa)
- what precedes and what follows is a non word character
  (e.g. quote, parenthesis, etc.)

```
string title = "ThisIsAnExampleTitleHELLO-WORLD2019T.E.S.T.(Test)[Test]\"Test\"'Test'";
string[] split =  Regex.Split(title, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=\\W)(?=\\W)"); 
split = (from e in split select e.Trim()).ToArray();
string newtitle = string.Join(" ", split);

This Is An Example Title HELLO-WORLD 2019 T.E.S.T. (Test) [Test] "Test" 'Test'
```

Note: You might also want to add this assertion to the regex alternation:

```
(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W)
```

We got away with this here, because this boundary condition never happened.  But you might need it with other inputs.

Comment: I ran into one issue, when it comes to single letter words like `A` and `I`, it will not separate because it uses the `ALL UPPERCASE` rule (two uppercase next to each other). `ATitleExample` becomes `ATitle Example`.

Comment: @MattMcManis This is an edge case which will potentially break all of the answers given here.  You would need to do more work to cover such  cses.a

Comment: Maybe I can run the output of this through a second regex to fix those.

Answer (score 9):

Aiming for simplicity rather than huge regex, I would recommend this code with small simple patterns (comments with explanation are in code):

```
string str = "ThisIsAnExampleTitleHELLO-WORLD2019T.E.S.T.(Test)\"Test\"'Test'[Test]";
// insert space when there is small letter followed by upercase letter
str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
// insert space whenever there's digit followed by a ltter
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\d)(?=[A-Za-z])", " ");
// insert space when there's letter followed by digit
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\d)", " ");
// insert space when there's one of characters ("'[ followed by letter or digit
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?=[(\[""'][a-zA-Z0-9])", " ");
// insert space when what preceeds is on of characters ])"'
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=[)\]""'])", " ");
```

Comment: If commenting was your main concern you could enable x-mode or use inline comments i.e. `(?#insert space when there's letter followed by digit)`.

Comment: @revo I used standard C# comments :) I think it's more readable.

Comment: You could also write such kind of readable comments by setting *standard* `x` modifier which enables you to write multiline, indented perfect comments. It's not simple by the way. Just split. .

Answer (score 8):

You could reduce the requirements to shorten the steps of a regular expression using a different interpretation of them. For example, the first requirement would be the same as to say, ***preserve capital letters if they are not preceded by punctuation marks or capital letters.***

The following regex works almost for all of the mentioned requirements and may be extended to include or exclude other situations:

```
(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}
```

You have to use [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_) method and use  `$0` as substitution string.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/InozZ3/1)

.NET (See it [in action](https://ideone.com/Nz3Gte)):

```
string input = @"ThisIsAnExample.TitleHELLO-WORLD2019T.E.S.T.(Test)""Test""'Test'[Test]";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, @" $0"));
```

Comment: This is an interesting way. Which rule can be added to fix `HELLO-WORLD2019` by spacing the `2019`?

Comment: Add `(?<=\p{L})\d` within an alternation: `(?<!^|[A-Z\p{P}])[A-Z]|(?<=\p{P})\p{P}|(?<=\p{L})\d`.

Comment: I have one other issue, single letter words like `A` and `I` won't space. `ATitleExample` becomes `ATitle Example`.

Comment: What about something like `OTPIsADevice`?

Comment: It starts to get complicated. `OTPIs ADevice` maybe I can run the output through a second filter. Rules: If a word starts with 2 Uppercase letters `ADevice`, add a space after the first letter `A Device`. And if an `ALL UPPERCASE` word ends in a `lowercase` letter `OTPIs`, add a space before the last two letters `OTP Is`.